# How to act upon Exceptions differently

Tags: php, exception

I am using a third party API which throws general Exceptions like :

```
// Some code
throw new Exception("Invalid Name");

// Some code 
throw new Exception("Invalid Password");
```

Now in my code i am catching exception which i think is not a good way

```
try {
    // my code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if($e->getMessage() == "Invalid Name")
       // handle name exception
    if($e->getMessage() == "Invalid Password")
      // handle password exception
}
```

I already asked them to throw specific exceptions for better handling but they refused to do so.

I am after if there is any good way to handle different exceptions when there is only `Exception` class is being thrown

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that you can do better than that. Those exception are thrown by the same method?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/src/Registration.php in the `codeRequest` method